# Difference between WindowProc and CallWindowProc?

Tags: winapi, wndproc

What is the difference between [`WindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CallWindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

I can imagine when registering a new window class I can specify my own **WindowProc** for it.
This leaves the question: When and what for do I use **CallWindowProc** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subclass a window using [`SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx) to assign a new `WindowProc()` to the window, the replacement `WindowProc()` uses `CallWindowProc()` when it needs to call the window's original `WindowProc()`:

[Subclassing a window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#subclassing_window)

The preferred way to subclass a window is to use [`SetWindowSubClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

[Safer subclassing](https://web.archive.org/web/20120614031229/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx)

Comment: The example makes it clearer. I also made the mistake to compare a callback function to an API function.

Answer (score -1):

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/ms633571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `CallWindowProc` is used for subclassing.